# Intellij - CSS colour boxes in left margin

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea

I'm writting a CSS file using IntelliJ, and want to know how to get the box of colour that appears on the left when a colour is being declared in the code.
For example, if I write:

```
h1{background: red;}
```

A red box to the left of this line would appear. For some reason it's not appearing and I don't know why. How can I get this back?

Comment: Can you share more of your code please

Comment: Do you have [this option enabled](http://i.imgur.com/8vjFonQ.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable `Show CSS color preview...` in the preferences. For to do that go to Preferences > Editor > General > Appearance.

[image]